# How do I create padding inside a list of text fields?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a registration widget. Most of the work I have done is finished and works.
I only have some issues with padding between my listed textfields.
How do I create a padding?

According to stack overflow this post is mostly code so here is some plain text because I really cannot say more about this, I have aksed my question and provided my code.

```
var entries = [];

class RegisPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RegisPageState createState() => _RegisPageState();
}

class _RegisPageState extends State<RegisPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Map<String,TextEditingController> textEditingControllers = {};
    var textFields = <TextFormField>[];
    entries.forEach((str) {
      var textEditingController = TextEditingController();
      textEditingControllers.putIfAbsent(str, ()=>textEditingController);
      return textFields.add(
        TextFormField(
        controller: textEditingController,
        decoration: 
          InputDecoration(
            labelText: str, 
            border:
             OutlineInputBorder(
               borderRadius: 
                BorderRadius.circular(25.0)
              )
            ),
        ),
      );
    });

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Registration'),
        ),
        body:Center(
          child:
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child:
                Column(
                  children:[
                    Column(children:textFields),
                    RaisedButton(
                      child: Text("Register"),
                        onPressed: (){
                        entries.forEach((str){
                          print(textEditingControllers[str].text);
                        });
                      }
                    )
                  ]
                )
              )  
            )  
          );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add spacing you can just wrap the `TextFormField` with padding like this:

```
  Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(left, top, right, bottom),
    child: TextFormField(
      controller: textEditingController,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: str, 
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: 
          BorderRadius.circular(25.0)
        )
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Then instead of having a list of `TextFormField` you could do `List<Widget>`
Like this:

`var textFields = <Widget>[];`

Everything should still work the same, but now you can specify padding/spacing on all sides.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok great, I made a few changed to my answer because the list needs to be of type Widget but I am glad it works! If you could upvote this and mark it as correct that would mean a lot!

Comment: I accepted your answer, Thanks a lot... I just couldn't figure out why padding wouldn't work, just needed someone to notice the list of TextFormFields and not a list of Widgets.

Comment: Haha, of course, it happens to the best of use. Thank you!